# AFNetworking downloading custom file

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to download a custom file type from my server using AFNetworking - for some reason, it's saying it successfully downloaded the file, but it seems like the result is corrupt.

This is what I get in the log:

```
2013-04-20 11:17:40.326 app[18083:907] start downloads
2013-04-20 11:17:40.392 app[18083:907] Sent 283280 of 283280 bytes, /var/mobile/Applications/187878BC-9D5A-4E1C-9EE4-34512D93BF68/Documents/theprice.cm
2013-04-20 11:17:40.393 app[18083:907] Successfully downloaded file to /var/mobile/Applications/187878BC-9D5A-4E1C-9EE4-34512D93BF68/Documents/theprice.cm
```

My internet is fast, but It surely did not download 283,280 bytes in .04 seconds.

Here is my AFNetworking code:

```
NSLog(@"start downloads");

NSString *urlpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com/ygp6bcckll8mw62.cm"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlpath]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"theprice.cm"]];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes, %@", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, path);
}];

[operation start];
```

When I try to access the file contents, as one would expect: it's empty.

Any ideas with regards to why this isn't properly downloading a custom file type? (.cm) Am I missing something in the AFNetworking code to make it behave oddly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `outputStream` is being properly flushed and closed?  It might be that the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is marking the transfer as successfully complete once all the data is received, but has no awareness of any particularly latency and/or requirements in writing to persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking won't sent an open message to its output stream. Albeit, it does send a `close` message to it when it is finished or when an error occurred. You may try if sending `open` to the output stream before starting the request will help.

Otherwise be warned that AFNetworking won't check for potential failure codes from the stream, and won't guarantee that all received bytes have been written completely into to stream.